# Is it possible to control Google Places Autocomplete SearchBox service predictions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-redux

Is it possible to control (enable/disable) Google Places Autocomplete SearchBox (google.maps.places.SearchBox) service predictions? I need Autocomplete after user entered 3 characters

this is my search box:

```
<input id='mapLocation' onChange={this.autoComplete.bind(this)} type='text' placeholder='' ref='search_location' required autofocus />
```

this is my autocomplete method:

```
autoComplete() {
        let that = this;
        let google = window.google;
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.state.AutoCompleteSdk, 'places_changed', function () {
            if (!that.stopPropagation_) {
                let places = that.state.AutoCompleteSdk.getPlaces();
                _.map(places, (place) => {
                    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        isChecked: true,
                        position: { lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng() },
                        icon: markerIcon
                    });
                    marker.bindTo('map', that.state.AutoCompleteSdk, 'map');
                    that.state.listOfmarks.push(marker);
                    that.state.selectedPlaces.push({ formatted_address: place.formatted_address, isChecked: true, place: place });
                })
                that.stopPropagation_ = true;
                that.setState({}, () => that.resetMarker());
            }
        });
    }
```

and state AutoCompleteSdk is :

```
let AutoCompleteSdk = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('mapLocation'));
```

I tried AutoCompleteSdk.unbindAll(); but it is not working. Please give me a suggetion how to off that autocomplete for first 3 characters. and after i need to start that

Comment: You can use [AutocompleteService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#AutocompleteService) and build your own autocomplete that implements your behaviour.

Comment: if I use AutocompleteService, it is giving only top 5 records need more than that.